# how to pass information to a view from a controller then getting it back in the controller with asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty sure it's easy but I can't seem to find it.

I have 2 table linked together in sql;

```
   table1 with field named idTable1, info
   table2 with field named idTable1, idTable2, moreInfo
```

when I show the view that can add a new row into table2, I have access to idTable1

```
 <%=Html.Encode(Model.idTable1)%>
```

but when I submit for form, I'm losing that information, in the controller the IdTable1 is now empty

how to fix that "problem" ?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Html.Encode`, you might try using `Html.Hidden`. Example:

```
<form>
...
<%= Html.Hidden("idTable1", Model.idTable1) %>
...
</form>
```

This will submit the value for `idTable1` along with the form data.